# Closest element and prev()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to addClass to closest p in click event:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7gFf/2/

But this couldnot add or remove class to p element. What is wrong with click event.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest()` searches *ancestors*, not *siblings*. Remove it, `prev()` will find the previous sibling `<p>` for you (you can always pass in the `p` selector to ensure it only selects the previous paragraph):

```
$(this).prev("p").toggleClass("showComment");
```

Comment: I would like to add that prev() (with no selector) will select the previous sibling of any type.  Use prev("p") to get the nearest prior sibling of type P.

Comment: @Keith: It was there a while ago. I've put it back.

Comment: @Keith: It doesn't get the *"nearest prior sibling of type P"*. The `.prev()` method will always only look at the immediate sibling. If that sibling doesn't match the selector, then an empty jQuery object is returned.

Comment: @patrick - That makes sense - I realized the functionality I was thinking of would be equivalent to `.prevAll("p").last()`

Comment: @Keith: You're very close, except that you'd need `.prevAll("p").first()` or `.prevAll("p:first")`. Though it doesn't seem to be documented, the elements are returned in the reverse order of their appearance in the DOM, so the nearest one comes first.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) navigates up the tree. Since the .cnt isn't *inside* the paragraph, this won't work. You are probably looking for just the previous paragraph, such as:

```
$(e.target).prev("p").toggleClass("showComment");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both .closest() and .prev() to get this to work.

```
$('.cnt').bind("click", function (e) {
      $(this).prev().toggleClass("showComment");
    });
```